# Elliptical orbit verses extreme axis

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, adaptability, axial-tilt

What could be the differences between adaptations to a planet with extreme axial tilt and one with a highly elliptical orbit? The only difference I think is the tilt world's winters could be avoided by migration.

Comment: I'd say this needs some more focus, or it'll attract votes to close.

Comment: Well, for once assuming that both worlds have equal day-length the tilt world will have both hemispheres experiencing an entire season of darkness, while the day night cycle on the eliptic world's stays constant.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight: Not entirely correct. A quarter year after one pole points towards the sun, the planet's north-south axis will be at right angles to the sun's equator, and if the planet rotates, it will then have days and night of equal length. This is the case for Uranus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus#Axial_tilt

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I'm aware of that, hence my use of season, by which I meant roughly a quarter of the year.

Comment: @JoeSmith this is unclear, I don't understand the phrase *"differences between adaptations to a planet"*, shouldn't that be *"differences in climate on a planet"* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Elliptical orbit**

This planet will experience very long winters and very short summers, since the planet moves more quickly at perihelion (when it is closest to the sun) than at aphelion (when it is farthest away). Any lifeforms are likely to either (a) hibernate through the long, cold winters, with a short blooming around summer, or shelter deep underground during the short, hot summer, *or*  (b) rapidly adapt to the changing seasons. The latter will not just include adjusting to heat or cold, but also to bright or dim light. At perihelion, radiation and solar flares could also be a danger that the life has to adjust to, if it doesn't shelter underground.

During winter, the entire planet cools, while during summer, the entire planet heats, with no escape from extreme temperatures. Ice will build up over the long winter and melt rapidly during summer. During the entire year, days and nights will be of equal length, so all parts will receive some sunlight all year long.

**Extreme axial tilt**

Summers and winters will be of equal length. Near solstices, most of one hemisphere will experience only sunlight, while the other hemisphere will experience only darkness, with an equatorial twillight band. This is actually the case for the planet [Uranus](https://%20en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus#Axial_tilt) in our solar system.

The predominant winds at the surface will be from winter to summer, while the opposite is true in the upper atmosphere, as hot air rises from the summer side, sucking cold air in from the winter side. This transports heat from the summer side to the winter side, making seasons less extreme than they would otherwise be (but still quite extreme). The moisture brought with the hot air will fall as rain near the equator and as snow winter-side. This snow may pile very high during winter and subsequently melt during spring, causing rivers flowing towards the equator and possibly further. Animal life adapted to winter may use these rivers to migrate to the opposite hemisphere, while life adapted to summer will have to walk towards the equator or glide on the last high-atitude summer winds. Equatorial lifeforms will require little adaptation, but may migrate short distances to stay in light near solstices.

Near equinoxes, the entire planet will experience equal days and nights, but the sunlight will fall at a shallower angle away from the equator, for less incipient light and heat. The hemisphere that just experienced summer will however retain a lot of heat in the ground, while the other hemisphere will retain cold, so the hemispheres will not experience equal temperatures until some time after the equinox - similar to how the coldest part of winter in Europe is in February rather than December or January. (Thanks to @imtaar for making me aware of my earlier error in thinking.)

Comment: For extreme axial tilt planet, near equinoxes (last paragraph in your answer) the light rays fall at equator at ~90° while at poles they fall at ~0°. Average temperatures will vary at different latitudes similar to those on earth.

Comment: @imtaar: The light rays will only fall ~90° at the equator at midday. Evenings and mornings, they fall at ~0°, and at night, there will be no light at all. But you are right in that there will be differences at different latitudes. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Do you have sources for the circulation pattern or is it just conjecture on your part? I tried to look into it a while back, but couldn't find anything. I'm not convinced that the thermal difference is always strong enough to overcome the coriolis force. My guess would be that very little heat is transported across the equator as long as the day-length is below, say a week.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight: On Earth, hot air rises at the warm equator and moves towards the North Pole. Because of the coriolis force, this movement is broken up into three convection cells, the Hadley cell, the Ferrel cell and the Polar cell. Overall, though, the pattern is warm air moving away from the equator and cold air moving towards it. Barring other information, I imagine that a similar pattern will exist on a planet with a hot and a cold hemisphere. https://www.weather.gov/source/zhu/ZHU_Training_Page/winds/Wx_Terms/Flight_Environment.htm

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Yes, but the coriolis force the are is pushed ever further east/ westward. This is what causes the formation of the circulation cells in the first place. This force will be present on any world and it will break the circulation pattern. However, given how different detailed simulations of the atmospheres of tidally locked planets look compared to what you would expect, we might very well both be wrong.

Comment: Thank you. That's plenty to work with

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling many details so I am adding some of them.

**Solar system analogies**

In the first case, the star is sun-like and the planet X with extreme axial tilt is earth like (same average distances, radii, energy, atmosphere etc.) but with axial tile of 97.7° (like Uranus).

In the second case, the star is sun-like and the planet Y with a highly elliptical orbit is earth like (same radii, energy, atmosphere etc. but at aphelion, the planet is away like Mars and at perihelion, the planet is close like Venus).

Planet HD 20782 b has an orbital eccentricity of 0.97 (Read [here](https://www.quora.com/What-planet-in-the-universe-has-the-highest-known-orbital-eccentricity)).

[image]

**Planet X**

As shown in Figure, at position A, it is all day at north pole (temperature may reach 70°C,158°F) and all night at south pole (temperature may reach -150°C, -238°F) for quarter of a year. Opposite will happen at position C.

[image]

At position B and D, it will be normal day-night cycle as on earth with average temperatures similar to those on earth at different latitudes.

On Uranus, Wind speeds can reach up to 560 miles per hour (900 kilometers per hour). On Planet X, wind speeds could be even higher.

**Planet Y**

At aphelion, the planet receives nearly half as much energy from the Sun as does Earth and it is a frozen world with average temperature -65°C, -85°F. At perihelion, the planet receives nearly twice as much energy from the Sun as does Earth and it is a very hot world with average temperature 150°C, 302°F.

Day-night cycle will be same as on earth.

Comment: What eccentricity did you use for Planet Y? Remember that Planet Y only needs to be 40% farther from its sun at perihelion than at aphelion to receive half as much sunlight. That isn't all that extreme an orbit.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen Planet HD 20782 b has an orbital eccentricity of 0.97 (see my revised answer). What you are saying is not mentioned in question.

Comment: Wouldn't have been better to ask for those missing details to the OP, instead of forcing your assumption on them?